# WCF registering dependencies for IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET MVC i can register dependencies at `Gloabal.asax`. and it works fine.

When i want to create a WCF service and register dependencies with a container, where do I register depencencies for IIS?

In project I dont see a global asax kinda startup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is stateless. This means that every time a call hits your WCF service, it pretty much fires off a fresh instance. I also needed to init some stuff in my WCF services that are hosted in IIS, and my solution was to use an initialization type of attribute. I created my attribute like so:

```
public class InitializationBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior 
{
    public InitializationBehavior()
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
                                     BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // <---- put your init stuff here
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }
}
```

You can then slap that attribute on the implementation of your service:

```
[InitializationBehavior]
public class YouService: IYourService
{
    // your WCF service
}
```

Here is a good read on using all the methods that IServiceBehavior has to offer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/22/wcf-extensibility-iservicebehavior.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WCF services are orthogonal to IIS. If you are hosting services in ASP.NET application, then you should use `Global.asax`. If you're writing console application - register services in Main method. In case of windows service use ServiceBase.OnStart method for this purpose.

Comment: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/ - This article explains how to write your custom service initialization behavior, where you can initialize your container.